# Detect whether the word you is a subject or object pronoun based on sentence context.

Tags: python, regex, nlp, linguistics

Ideally using regex, in python. I'm making a simple chatbot, and it's currently having problems responding to phrases like "I love you" correctly (it'll throw back "You love I" out of the grammar handler, when it should be giving back "You love me").

In addition, I'd like it if you could think of good phrases to throw into this grammar handler, that'd be great. I'd love some testing data.

If there's a good list of transitive verbs out there (something like a "top 100 used") it may be acceptable to use that and special case the "transitive verb + you" pattern.

Comment: Have a look at my Answer; I've updated it. ;-)

Comment: Hi, any updates? I want some simple resolutions to solve some simple problems too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is a syntactic analyser (aka [parser](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing))- this can be done by a rule-based system as described by @Dr.Kameleon, or statistically. There are many implementations out there, one being the [Stanford](https://github.com/dasmith/stanford-corenlp-python) one. These will generally tell you what the syntactic role of a word is (e.g. subject "You are here", or object "She like you"). How you use that information to turn statements into questions is a whole different can of worms. For English, you can get a fairly simple rule-based system to work OK.

Answer (score 4):

Well, what you're trying to implement is definitely very challenging but also very difficult.

### Logic

As a starter, I would look a bit into the Grammar rules first.

**Basic sentence structure :**

- SUBJECT + TRANSITIVE VERB + OBJECT
- SUBJECT + INTRANSITIVE VERB

*(Of course, we could also talk about "Subject+Verb+Indirect Object+Direct Object" formats, etc (e.g. I give you the ball) but this would get too complicated for now...)*

Obviously, this scheme is VERY simplistic, but let's stick to that for now.

Then (another over-simplistic assumption), that ***each part is a single word***.

so basically you have the following **Sentence Scheme :**

```
WORD WORD WORD
```

which could be generally matched using a **regex** like :

```
([\w]+)\s+([\w]+)\s+([\w]+)?
```

**Explanation :**

```
([\w]+)     # first word (=subject)
\s+         # one or more spaces    
([\w]+)     # second word (=verb)
\s+         # one or more spaces
([\w]+)?    # (optional) third word (=object - if the verb is transitive)
```

---

Now, obviously to formulate sentences like "You love me" and not "You love I", your algorithm should also "understand" that :

- The third part of the sentence has the role of the Object
- Since "I" is a personal pronoun (used only in nominative case : "as a subject"), we should you its "accusative form" (=as an object); so, for this purpose, you may also need **e.g.** personal pronoun tables like :

> - I   - my   - me
> - You - your - you
> - He  - his  - him
> - etc...

Just a few ideas... (purely out of my enthusiasm for linguistics :-))

---

### Data

As for the wordlists you are interested in, just a few samples :

- [330 Most Common English Verbs](http://www.acme2k.co.uk/Acme/3star%20verbs.htm) (most - if not all of them - are
  transitive)
- [Personal Pronouns Chart](http://josecarilloforum.com/imgs/PronounChart.png)

Comment: "I go to school" would not work with this scheme.
Well I think there should be some linguistic libraries out there.
It's not just challenging, rather more over-challenging.

Comment: @daemonfire300 well, obviously "I go to school" (Subject + Verb + Preposition + Object) would NOT work with my scheme. What I suggested to the OP (the same thing I myself would do actually) is to start with the simplest version possible, and start adding to it as it goes... :-)